# What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^2 - 3A + 4I$, given the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let eigenvalues of $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ be $1,-2$ and eigenvectors be $x_1$ & $x_2$ respectively. Then eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^2-3A+4I$ would be?

We know that eigenvalues can be calculated by substituting in the equation of new matrix. But what is the relation of eigenvectors with new matrix in such cases?

Comment: Try computing $(A^2-3A+4I)x_1$ and $(A^2-3A+4I)x_2$, and see what that tells you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $A v = \lambda v$, and $P$ is a polynomial, then $P(A) v = P(\lambda) v$.

Comment: So it's obvious that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then it's an eigenvector of $P(A)$. But is the converse true too?

Comment: Not quite: e.g. if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are eigenvalues of $A$ with $P(\lambda_1) = P(\lambda_2) = \mu$, then any nonzero linear combination of an eigenvector of $A$ for $\lambda_1$ and an eigenvector for $\lambda_2$ is an eigenvector of
$P(A)$ for eigenvalue $\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvectors stay the same. For convenience take the eigenvalue 1 and eigenvector x1. Then,
((A^2) - 3A + 4I) .x1=((1) ^2)x1 - 3.(1.x1)+ 4 (x1) =2.x1. Similarly the others.

Comment: Will the eigen vectors always remain same irrespective of the operations done on matrix? Do they depend on eigen values and may change if eigen values are not distinct or real?

Comment: In which cases the eigen vectors may be different?

Comment: Read Carefully the first comment and the first answer.